# CSS: transition a transformation once, then reset it without transition

Tags: css, transform, transition

Basically I want to transition my element by adding a class `.anim` every 5 seconds but reset it ever 1 second w/o transitioning the property.

The effect I want is to spin the arrow around once every 5 seconds.

What's the best way to do this?

```
setInterval(function(){
    var $el = $("a.inbox");

    $el.addClass('anim');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $el.removeClass('anim');
    }, 1000);
    console.log($el);
}, 5000);

a.inbox:before {
  content: '⇧';
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  margin-left: 5px;

  transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
}

a.inbox {
  &.anim:before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(540deg);
  }
}

<a href="#" class="inbox">Inbox</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only put the `transition` property inside the `a.inbox.anim` style. This will mean that the transition is only applied when changing to that class, but won't be applied when it is removed.